# How can I compare elements from a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists of strings and I would like to obtain the largest string on each inner list and store them into another list. For example:

```
tableData = [['apples','bananas','oranges','cherries'],
            ['Alice','Bob','Carol','David'],
            ['dogs','cats','moose','goose']]

widths = [0] * len(tableData)
```

I want to store in widths[0], the width of the longest string in tableData[0], in widths[1] the width of the longest string in tableData[1], and so on. How can I compare the length of the words in order to get the greater?

The only way I thought is doing this:

```
for f in range(len(tableData)):
    for c in range(len(tableData[1])):
        max = len(tableData[f][c])
        if max < len(tableData[f][c+1]):
            max = len(tableData[f][c+1])
    widths[f] = max
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where lies your difficulty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
widths = [len(max(lst, key=len)) for lst in tableData]
```

For your list of lists called `tableData`, this gives:

```
[8, 5, 5]
```

Explanation:

`[max(lst, key=len) for x in tableData]` gives you a list containing the longest string of each nested list. Using `len()`, one then obtains the lengths of these.

The same result can be achieved using:

```
widths = [len(sorted(lst, key=len)[-1]) for lst in tableData]
```

Where `sorted(lst, key=len)` will sort the elements of each list by length, from shortest to longest. Using `[-1]` one can then obtain the last value of each list, i.e. the longest strings. `len()`will then compute their lengths.

Comment: This worked just fine, thanks a lot. I wasn't aware of the max() function so I'm doing research to find out more about it.

Comment: No problem. The important part here is that [max(lst_of_strings)](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#max) compares the strings lexicographically, i.e. returns the string which comes last when sorted alphabetically. Hence, to get the longest strings, we need `max(lst_of_strings, key=len)`. To then obtain their actual lengths, `len()` can be used.

Answer (score -1):

Don't worry about initializing widths. [List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) are your friends here.

```
# creates a list of lists of word lengths
lengths_of_words = [[len(word) for word in x] for x in tableData]

# finds the max length for each list
widths = [max(y) for y in lengths_of_words]
```

Could also be shortened to

```
widths = [max([len(word) for word in x]) for x in tableData]
```

---

This is the old, incorrect answer if people would like to learn from my mistake:

```
widths = [len(max(x)) for x in tableData]
```

Comment: You are finding the length of the 'max' item in the list in which case would be 'oranges' as o is higher than the other begining letters. When the string with the most length is cherries. (in the first list)

Comment: Thanks for the help @Wright, that's what I get for charging in like I know something